# Query for counting total number of submissions per researcher

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have 3 tables relating to Submission and Researcher.

Submission table:

```
SubmissionID, Type, Title, Status, Comment, CapturedOnRIMS, NumberOfAuthors, NumberOfWitsAuthors, TotalPages, PagesInPreamble, PagesInText, NumberOfChapters, Location, PublicationID, CESMID, SubmissionDate
```

Researcher table:

```
ResearcherID, FirstName, Surname, RegistrationDate, QualificationType, JobName, Availability, SchoolID
```

ResearcherSubmission (relational table):

```
SubmissionID, ResearcherID
```

I am trying to create a query that display a count of the total number of submissions per researcher. A researcher can have many submissions, and a submission can be done by many researchers, hence the relational table.

Desired output:

```
Name             Number of Submission
John Doe                   14
William Smith              10
Ellie Carter               12
Susan Wright               10
```

Comment: you have to show some effort of your own. i am pretty sure that if you follow a basic SQL tutorial, you can come up with the answer to this question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `JOIN` the tables and do a `group by`:

```
select r.FirstName, r.LastName, count(*) as no_of_sub
from Researcher r
  join ResearcherSubmission rs on r.ResearcherID = rs.ResearcherID
  join Submission s on s.SubmissionID = rs.SubmissionID
group by r.FirstName, r.LastName
```